# Getting public photos from Instagram account without login

Tags: ios, instagram

I want to get all the photos or public photos from my Instagram account, without logging in to it.

Is there an API provided by Instagram to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. The Instagram API requires Authentication to retrieve a certain accounts pictures. Check out the [API Console](http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/) on Instagram's developer website to see which methods require authentication and which of them don't. I know you can retrieve tags, popular pictures, and search users. Good luck!

Comment: That link is now broken